# In SELECT change field from NULL to NOT NULL

Tags: sql, t-sql

In a `SELECT` statement can a field be changed from `NULL` to `NOT NULL`?

I have to use this field in a `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` which does not allow a constraint on a nullable column.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT IMIDXDESC
  INTO WorkTable 
  FROM LiveTable
```

`IMIDXDESC` is `NULL` in LiveTable and I would like it changed to `NOT NULL` in WorkTable.

I know I can do a `ALTER` Table after the `SELECT` but I was wondering if I can do it right in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: In order to do what you want you have to specify the value instead of the NULL value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(IMIDXDESC,'') AS IMIDXDESC INTO WorkTable 
FROM LiveTable
```

[ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
SELECT COALESCE(IMIDXDESC,'') AS IMIDXDESC INTO WorkTable 
FROM LiveTable
```

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: Only `ISNULL` has the desired effect of making the new column nullability `NOT NULL`